# How to export a profile of a calibrated image with an imagej macro

Tags: imagej

i wrote a little macro, that locates spheres on a spatially calibrated (Dicom-) image. Once found, it draws lots! of lines and saves the brightness profiles along these lines to a csv file. So far, this works nice and fast. This is the piece of code, that extracts the profiles and saves them:

```
for (i=0; i < 360; i++){
    run("Clear Results"); 
    angle = i*2*PI/360;
    makeLine(xm,ym,(xm+(length*sin(angle))), (ym-(length*cos(angle))));
    profile = getProfile();
    for (j=0; j<profile.length; j++) {
        setResult("Value", j, profile[j]);
    }
    updateResults;
    saveAs("Results",path + "\\angle_"+i+".csv");
}
```

My problem is, that the actual scale is not exported. I get something like this:

```
1,3070.070
2,3069.000
3,3069.986
4,3053.646
```

but i want

```
0.4395 3070
0.8789 3070
1.3184 3070
1.7578 069.8994
```

And so on. I tried to modify this line a little:

```
setResult("Value", j*xscale, profile[j]);
```

but this does not work. I also tried to plot the profiles and then read and save them.

```
for (i=0; i < 360; i++){
        run("Clear Results"); 
        angle = i*2*PI/360;
        makeLine(xm,ym,(xm+(length*sin(angle))), (ym-(length*cos(angle))));
        run ("Plot Profile");
        Plot.getValues(xplot,yplot);
        for (j=0; j< xplot.length; j++){
            print (xplot[j],yplot [j]);         
        }

        selectWindow("Log");
        saveAs("Text",path + "\\angle_"+i+".csv");
        print("\\Clear");
        selectWindow("04");
    }
```

(Sorry, the window switching is still experimental and the profiles are not closing..)

This works in principle but it is of course PAINFULLY slow. So my question is.... How do i extract not online line numbers but the correct scale in a profile?
Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first column is just a non editable line number. The code must be changed like this:

```
for (i=0; i < 360; i++){
    run("Clear Results"); 
    angle = i*2*PI/360;
    makeLine(xm,ym,(xm+(length*sin(angle))), (ym-(length*cos(angle))));
    profile = getProfile();
    for (j=0; j<profile.length; j++) {
        setResult("xvalues", j, j*dx);
        setResult("yvalues", j, profile[j]);
    }
    updateResults;
    saveAs("Results",path + "\\angle_"+i+".csv");
}
```